# install python3 on VM without using internet

Tags: python-3.x, gitlab, virtual-machine

I need to install python 3 on my virtual machine (I have python 2.7) but I don't have access to internet from my *VM*. Is there any way to do that  without using internet I have access to a private gitlab repository and private dokcer hub.

Comment: Python 2 has been end-of-lifed for over 2 years, and "old" for almost a decade.  You might need to rebuild your VM on top of a more modern Linux distribution.

Comment: What operating system is your VM using?

Answer (score 0):

### Using GitLab

Ultimately, you can put whatever resources you need to install Python3 directly in GitLab.

For example, you could use the [generic packages registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/generic_packages/) to upload the files you need and download them from GitLab in your VM. For example, you can redistribute the files from [python.org/downloads](https://www.python.org/downloads/) this way.

If you're using a debian-based Linux distribution like Ubuntu, you could even provide the necessary packages in the [GitLab debian registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/debian_repository/) (disabled by default, but can be enabled by an admin) and just use your package manager like `apt install python3-dev` after configuring your apt lists to point to the gitlab debian repo.

#### Using docker

If you have access to dockerhub, technically you can access files from docker images as well. Here I'll assume you're using `ubuntu` or some debian-based distribution, but the same principle applies for any OS.

Suppose you build an image:

```
FROM ubuntu:<a tag that matches your VM version>

# downloads all the `.deb` files you need to install python3
RUN apt update && apt install --download-only python3-dev
```

You can push this image to your docker registry
Then on your VM, you can pull this image and extract the necessary install files from `/var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb` in the image then install using dpkg

Extract files from the image (in this case, to a temp directory)

```sh
image=myprivateregistry.example.com/myrepo/myimage
source_path=/var/cache/apt/archives
destination_path=$(mktemp -d)

docker pull "$image"
container_id=$(docker create "$image")
docker cp "$container_id:$source_path" "$destination_path"
docker rm "$container_id"
```

Install python3 using dpkg:

```sh
dpkg --force-all -i "${destination_path}/*.deb"
```